# Install bind9.8 on Debian 6

Tags: debian, samba, bind

As I am setting up a Samba4 domain, I would like to install Bind9.8, however, it is not in backports, and using testing would upgrade many other packages to testing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Compile it on your own. You complain about Debian testing, while using Samba 4?! That sounds odd as the website of Samba states: "Samba 4 is currently not yet in a state where it can replace existing production deployments."

Comment: I was not complaining, I was wanting to keep experimental software to a minimum. I do however require the GPO functionality of Samba4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Or just do it manually. No drama and works fine :)

```
wget ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.8.3-P1/bind-9.8.3-P1.tar.gz
tar xvzf bind-9.8.3-P1.tar.gz
cd bind-9.8.3-P1/
./configure --prefix=/opt/bind
make
make install
```

This will install the latest bind in /opt/bind so it won't conflict with the current system packages. If you want some extra features or non stadard options just read the README in the source directory.

Answer (score 2):

Better than installing the testing/unstable packages directly is to backport them yourself.  This would involve downloading the source package, and compiling it against packages in stable.

Add *only* a deb-src line (not a deb line) for testing or unstable to sources.list:

```
deb-src http://cdn.debian.net/debian testing main
```

Then run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get build-dep bind9
apt-get --build source bind9
```

The last command will fetch the source package to the current directory and try to build it.  If it is successful, you'll have new .deb files in the current directory when it is finished which you can install with `dpkg -i`

Comment: Why is that better?

Comment: because it keeps you from also installing dependencies from testing.  Since packages from testing are far more likely to be buggy, and testing gets no security support, the fewer packages installed from testing the better.

Comment: for example, for this package, he would have to upgrade his openssl libraries to the testing versions, my way he instead compiles against the openssl already in stable and therefore doesn't lose security support for openssh

Comment: Only if it works with the old version of the libs...

Comment: If it doesn't, then the Build-Depends: of the package are mis-declared.  The build-depends of the testing/unstable bind9 source package are currently satisfiable in stable.   In the case when one is backporting and not all the Build-Depends are satisfiable in stable, one can often just first backport those.

Answer (score 0):

You could a technique called [pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html) in APT. Basically you can install software from unstable or testing without upgrading you whole system.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I did it for Gallery2.  Just get the package from sid by pinning it.  All packages go to squeeze by default (*) and gallery2 comes from sid.

```
# cat /etc/apt/preferences
Package: *
Pin: release a=squeeze
Pin-Priority: 200

Package: gallery2
Pin: release a=sid
Pin-Priority: 999
```

Comment: You don't include a pin that lowers the priority of all the other sid packages, and without a default-release, the sid packages are all going to be strictly newer.